# Forcing a SCSI HDD to rewrite a damaged sector

Tags: linux, scsi, bad-blocks

For a SATA/PATA HDD, this would be the normal procedure: http://www.sjvs.nl/?p=12

But a customer of mine has an old server with actual SCSI drives.  I have tried re-writing the sector with `dd` to no avail; I keep getting the I/O error as per this quote from the above article:  "I have a case were using dd to overwrite the sector produces an IO error and no reallocation. But using hpdparm works and forces the reallocation. Amazing."

How do I skip the kernel's block layer and force the drive to rewrite a specific sector?  Lots of Googling hasn't found an answer.

PS -- SMART on SCSI HDDs works differently and doesn't show the reallocated sector count.

Comment: Did you try following the directions given in the article you linked?

Comment: The article referred to SATA/PATA HDDs.  I am using SCSI HDDs, and hdparm doesn't work with these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try sg3_utils for linux. It can do many things with SCSI/SAS disks. For blocks reassign it have "sg_reassign" utility.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Hopefully Google will now remember you as one of the last remaining SCSI experts on Earth. :-)